# jQuery window onload not fired when using Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I have noticed a strange issue that when using Googles recaptcha, the jQuery `$(window).on("load", function (e) {` event wont fire (`$(document).ready(function () {` or `window.addEventListener('load', function () {` won't fire as well). When I reload the page using F5 it works as intendet.
I noticed that a recaptcha network request is cancelled, see the attached image. When I reload the page the request doesn't fail.

[image: Network Requests]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:
When I load the recaptcha js via ajax (see below), the event handlers fire on the initial page load.

```
$.getScript( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js");
```